# How to join different monads?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am learning functional programming in js. I want to implement "sign in" using FP. Inside this case, there is a step need to compare the passed in password with the password stored in db, which actually compare a Task with a Maybe, and it will stop here, how to fix it? The below is the pseudo code:

```
import {Task} from "data.task"
import {Maybe} from "data.maybe"
import {pipe, equals, prop} from "ramda"

const getUserByUserName = userName => new Task((reject, result) => result({userName, password: "123"}))

const signIn = pipe(
    Maybe.fromNullable
    listM2(equals, 
        pipe(prop("userName"), getUserByUserName, prop("password")),
        prop("password")
    )
)

signIn({userName: "ron", password:"123"})
.fork(...) // here it will complain the fork is not found
```

Comment: Use a monad transformer… oh wait, this is javascript.

Comment: Just a question, but why do you need a Maybe in the first place? You aren't using Maybe on the user returned from the server, but on the user you *should* already have on the client. Is that correct?

Comment: @DustinStiles I just want to Maybe to protect if the passing stuff is null

Comment: Unfortunately my demo code was flawed in the implementation. I'll put up a gist in a few minutes that shows a few examples. Just remember `chain`

Comment: @DustinStiles, thanks for your efforts. I saw your deleted post, and I think there are probably two issues I want to fix: 1. it stopped us to use pointfree style because it has to refer the passing parameter "user.password". Another consideration is how about if the "user.password" is not coming from the parameter passed in at very beginning, I mean I try to consume some output in the previous monads.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue I had, it failed when passing null values and such. I was going to rewrite it, but I have to ask, why aren't you validating the password on the server? Sending user's password back down from the server in plain text is an incredibly large security flaw.

Comment: @Bergi When you build asynchronous control flows you benefit immensely from an (almost) monadic API, but monad transformers are ridiculous in Javascript? I don't get it! Fine, let's put in every imaginable feature into the `Promise` API until it literally can do anything. Lazyness/early exiting, null safety, exception handling (oh, it is already) and so much more.

Comment: @LUH3417: Not ridiculous, but not easy to use. I don't know any existing implementations that could just be pulled in. He probably will need to implement something that looks like a transformer himself.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, I misread your first comment. I hate it when people want to do awesome things (even if these are over-engineered sometimes) and then are discouraged by far more experienced people.

Comment: I figured out how to do it, but not feel very good. I posted another question to follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022140/how-to-fork-and-merge-monads