# How to fork and merge monads?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am learning monads and doing my first "login" case. The steps are simple:

1. User input userName and password;
2. From database, get user by userName, and get its password saved in database;
3. compare the input password with the one in the database.

From the above, there is a requirements to fork 2 monads and merge them to compare.

I read nearly all javascripts FP books and monads implementations I can think of, but still cannot found any solutions. The below is what I got so far, it works, but it looks complex and not very well readable. I am wondering if there is a standard way to handle this common problem. By they way, I am using falktale and ramda.

```
const Task = require('data.task')
const {chain, liftM2} = require('control.monads')
import {pipe, length, curry, prop, equals, tap} from 'ramda'

it.only('sign in', done => {
    const merge = curry((p, f, g, x) => liftM2(p, f(x), g(x)))

    const signIn = pipe(
        lift,
        chain(merge(equals,
            pipe(lift, map(prop('password'))),
            pipe(lift, map(prop('userName')), chain(getUserByUserName), map(prop('password')))
        ))
    )

    signIn({ userName: 'ron', password: '123' })fork(
        (err) => { console.log('error happens'); done(err) },
        matched => { expect(matched).to.eql(true); done() }
    )
})

const getUserByUserName = (id) => new Task((reject, result) => setTimeout(
    userName => userName === 'ron'
        ? reject('not found')
        : result({ userName: 'ron', password: '123' })
    , 0
))
```

Comment: [freeky](https://github.com/DrBoolean/freeky) is a good source for free monads

Comment: @Deadfish Thanks. It may be what I am looking for, watching the videos...

Comment: First of all I wouldn't utilize a lib when I'm learning a new paradigm. Libs are another layer of abstraction and make it harder to reason about new concepts and coding styles when you are not familiar with them. Besides I think you want too much too soon. Monads are a great abstraction for specific effects but they are also hard to grasp. New tools should be used sparingly in order to get time to understand their advantages and disadvantages. Monads of different types for instance are hard to compose. You need either monad transformers or nested `chain`/`bind` invocations.

Comment: In JavaScript there are few monad and almost no monad transformer implementations and a correspondingly small active community. Many problems which you are facing probably need to be solved by yourself. By the way, monads are even in Haskell a relatively new concept. Functional programming in the original sense consists of currying, combinators (higher order functions) and the composition of small, pure functions. However, all this is merely my personal opinion.

Comment: @LUH3417, thanks for your advice. Actually I read source  code from those lib not just use them, but that's really not enough compared with you. For the monad transformers I found the comments with this youtube is very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMCgJA8HScA, free monad or cata may save me, I am looking into.